# Django REST - input of some form fields occure twice on the backend

Tags: ajax, django, rest, api

Does anybody had the same problem? Some users' inputs are sent to the backend twice.

Data are stored in JSON's object. Key-value schema doesn't trigger the problem.
What users action can trigger this kind of problem? It doesn't happen every time, but only for some of the users.

```
"nameoffield": [
{
"url": "url-with-api-123",
"x": "y",
"a": "b",
"g": "k",
}

{
"url": "url-with-api-124"
"x": "y",
"a": "b",
"g": "k",
}
]
```

Data are copied, but only difference is that another number in url was generated.

Comment: if you dont show what code have you written how can we understand why it is getting triggered twice

Comment: What do you means by twice. is your request is getting triggered twice or data in a request is twice?

Comment: "nameoffield": [
 {
"url": "url-with-api-123",
"x": "y",
"a": "b",
"g": "k",
}

 {
"url": "url-with-api-124"
"x": "y",
"a": "b",
"g": "k",
}
]

User's input is copied, only difference is that another number in url was generated.

Comment: It happens in Django. Is it a problem with ajax? What user's action can trigger it and is there any solution in code to prevent it?

Comment: Please provide `Model`, `Serializer`, and `Viewsets`.